# Node REST API : Need to combine multiple routes in an object

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am building an application backend in TypeScript & NodeJS.

I have kept multiple routes logic in separate files(in single folder for each service) as :

```
> signup.ts   // export { router as signupRouter };
> signin.ts   // export { router as signinRouter };
> signout.ts  // export { router as signoutRouter };
```

I need to do this for all the services in future.

> I need to combine these routes so that I can specify them as a single entity in the **index.ts** file.

*Something like*:

```
import <object_that_combines_all> from './routes/<some_file_for_object>';
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users/<object_that_combines_all>'));
.
.
and so on
```

So that I don't have to mention each route **explicitly** in the index.ts file.

Comment: you could try with this  documentation http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router

Comment: Hi Siva, I know this. This is not what I want because I have kept different files for each endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way using the `router.use()` method in which we can combine the individual endpoints.

Assuming your file structure looks something like this -

```
/src
  /routes
    /users
      - signup.ts
      - signin.ts
      - signout.ts
 index.ts (your main app entry point)
```

You can utilize the `router.use()` method provided by `express.Router()`.

First, add a new `index.ts` file to the `/routes/users` folder to combine the multiple endpoints.

```
// /routes/users/index.ts

import * as express from 'express';
import { signupRouter } from './signupRouter';
import { signinRouter } from './signinRouter';
import { signoutRouter } from './signoutRouter';

const router = express.Router();

router.use(signupRouter);
router.use(signinRouter);
router.use(signoutRouter);

export {router as usersRouter};
```

Then in your main app entry point `index.ts`, do the following -

```
// /src/index.ts

import * as express from 'express';

import { usersRouter } from './routes/users/index.ts';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const app = express();

...

// Add your single entity entry point like this
app.use('/api/user', usersRouter);

...

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you'll need to dynamically discover the filenames (`readdir` or similar) and use  [*dynamic import*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) to import them. Dynamic import (`import()`) returns a promise of the module namespace object for a module.

For instance, using the [`fs/promises` version of `readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options), something along these lines (off-the-cuff, some tweaking probably required):

```
import { readdir } from "fs/promises";

const directoryPath = "/path/to/the/files";
const rexIsRouterFile = /^.+\.ts$/i;

async function loadRoutes(app) {
    const names = await readdir(directoryPath);
    for (const name of names.filter(name => rexIsRouteFile.test(name))) {
        const { router } of await import(`${directoryPath}/${name}`);
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−− dynamic import
        app.use('/api/users', router);
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes you have a TypeScript loader setup (for instance, as with `ts-node`). If you don't, you'll need to compile those TypeScript files to JavaScript before this runs, then change `.ts` to `.js` in `rexIsRouterFile`.